# Google chatbot: Response cards are suddenly not showing up in chatbot

Tags: chatbot, google-hangouts, google-chat

I have created a chatbot with bot url(API Gateway API using a lambda function). Response messages/cards are correctly returned to the bot. But today response messages are working as expected but suddenly cards are not showing up in the response to Bot , its blank (API logs are fine, I can see that api has returned the card ).

After a while I am able to see the response cards are showing up for the previous requests also.

After refreshing chatbot page, the response cards renders properly

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug. 
I normally send messages to my hangouts groups with reminders and they are not working since 2 days ago.

As far as i can see, if i have a button with a url link, the card dosent show.

Card without the link work fine.

As you said, if i close and reopen hangouts, the cards show.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an issue on the chat api tracker about that https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153412841

Edit: I was putting a textParagraph and buttons in the same widget. It was working before but now it doesn't. See the [doc](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/cards#widgetmarkup) .